# selecting alike rows in database table

Tags: php, mysql

This is the mysql table data which i have
 [image]

In this table above i want to run a query to

```
SELECT one  WHERE two=2 AS F1 AND two WHERE one=2 AS F2
SELECT one WHERE two=1 AS M1 AND two WHERE one=1 AS M2
```

so when i join `F1 and M1` and `F2 and M2` it will select only the rows that has the same number as two `WHERE one = 1 or 2` and the same number as one `WHERE two = 1 or 2` so when its grouped and echoed out out it will echo the numbers marked as grouped with colors. here is my query:

```
    SELECT * FROM friends AS f5
INNER JOIN 
((SELECT one FROM friends WHERE two =  '1') AS f1,
(SELECT two FROM friends WHERE one =  '1') AS f2,
(SELECT one FROM friends WHERE two =  '2') AS m1, 
(SELECT two FROM friends WHERE one =  '2') AS m2)
ON (f1.one  = m1.one AND f2.two = m2.two )
```

but it shows me an empty result when i query this code in the sql. please any help?

Comment: what result you want into this table can you explain it clearly ? i mean which number of rows or records you want using this table

Comment: Please add your expected result.

Comment: What is the result you expecting? Didn't understand what you want in result

Comment: Don't ask questions until you have marked answers on your other questions.